# Google Apps Marketplace SDK : setup a contextual gadget

Tags: google-api, google-apps-marketplace

Ok, so without much notification given, adding market place listings to your vendor profile is no longer possible. The 'create new listing' button is greyed out.

[image]

I need to make changes to an existing marketplace listing but that gives errors. We are forced into the new SDK.

So I went ahead and enabled the apps market SDK, filled out all details including images of all sizes, add a COB extension for the contextual gadget and saved the whole thing.

A minute later I return to make a modification and dang... error: "We are looking into this.".

@Google: HELP !

[image]

**UPDATE : I can reliably reproduce the error as explained [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-apps-marketplace-api/Rz3-gSzKV94).**

- Enable Google Apps Marketplace SDK in your project
- click on the gear icon, you will be directed to the old API Console
- Fill out all details
- Add a COB extension (Contextual gadget)
- Save everything
- Close the API console
- Go back to your cloud console ->  Google Apps Marketplace SDK
- Click on the gear icon again
- ERROR

Tested with several google accounts on different computeres and multiple projects on the cloud console.

Comment: It is now more clear why OpenId intermittently stopped working over the last weeks. It was foreseeable that it would become deprecated and now officially is with  the new Apps SDK.

Comment: We're still investigating - we're having mixed results in reproducing, which means it will take more time to find the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fill out parameter name and a paramter value or your cloud console will return errors and you will not be able to recover from this.

Ouch, that were 3 useless weeks....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@jonathanberi could we have a status on this issue, please? We are experiencing the exact same issue and we are unable to publish our app (which is ready) because of this bug. We have tried both creating a new Google Apps console project from scratch as well as modifying a draft of a yet to be published page with the same result. Is any information that we could provide to help?